# How to Run an Rscript as a crontab?

Tags: r, linux, cron, fedora

I'm using a fedora system and trying to automate an Rscript on my system. So I figured out the process of getting a crontab running. However it isn't working for my Rscript.

So to test whether I can run this Rscript normally from my root (root user and ~ directory) , I'm running:
`/bin/Rscript /home/computername/path_to_r_script/script.R > /root/Preprocessingv3.Rout`

But this is unable to find or import libraries and hits an error at the first library being imported as:
`Error in library(RForcecom) : there is no package called 'RForcecom'
Execution halted`

This is strange as historically I have been running this script many times as from command line as R CMD BATCH script.R > script.Rout by cding into that path_to_r_script folder as a non root user. Unless I'm missing something very fundamental of how Linux/fedora works, there should be no reason why a script that works from one location from one user but doesn't work from a different location from root user. So I'm guessing I'm not calling it the right way.

Could any one help me understand how we are supposed to automate Rscripts (and to an extent python scripts) as crontab? And what I have to do get it running on my system?

Comment: Compare the output from `.libPaths()` for "your" account and the account that is running the `cron` job.  Worst case set the library path in `script.R`.